# How to init MYSQL correctly

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I wrote a server using `cpp` to connect `mysql` with `libmysqlclient.a`, codes are like this:

```
#ifndef __IVC_MYSQLAPI_H__
#define __IVC_MYSQLAPI_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class ConnMysql {
public:
    ConnMysql();
    ~ConnMysql();
    int connInit(const char* host,int port,const char* user,const char* password,const char* database);
    int executeSql(const char* sql, std::vector<std::string> &v);
    void close();

private:
    MYSQL *sock;
    MYSQL  *my_sql;
};

ConnMysql::ConnMysql(){

}

ConnMysql::~ConnMysql(){

}

int ConnMysql::connInit(const char* host,int port,const char* user,const char* password,const char* database){
    my_sql = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (my_sql == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Init failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    sock = mysql_real_connect(my_sql, host,
                user, password, database, port, NULL, CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS);
    
    if (sock < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
}

int ConnMysql::executeSql(const char* sql, std::vector<std::string> &v) {
    mysql_query(sock, sql);
    MYSQL_RES *res_ptr;
    res_ptr = mysql_store_result(sock);
    if(res_ptr == nullptr) {   
        printf("Get data from mysql failed\n");            
        return -1;
    }  
    MYSQL_ROW sqlrow;
    int j = mysql_num_fields(res_ptr);          
    while((sqlrow = mysql_fetch_row(res_ptr))) {
        v.push_back(std::string(sqlrow[0]));
    }

    return 0;
}

void ConnMysql::close() {
    mysql_close(sock);
    sock=NULL;
    my_sql = NULL;
}

#endif //__IVC_MYSQLAPI_H__
```

The method called like this:

```
ConnMysql connsql = ConnMysql{};
fprintf(stderr, "begin to init\n");
if (connsql.connInit(ip, port, username, pwd, database) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "mysql init return failed\n");
    return -1;
}

std::string sql = "select env_code from env_codes where env_type = 1";
connsql.executeSql(sql.c_str(), v);
for (int len=0; len < v.size(); len++) {
    fprintf(stderr, "get: %s\n", v[len].c_str());
}
connsql.close();
```

I will get error such`Init failed` occasionally, not always. My questions are

1. Is there any wrong with my codes?  Forget to release something?
2. How can get the reason why mysql init failed?

Comment: Try checking the mysql error codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `mysql_real_connect` like this

```
if(mysql_real_connect(my_sql, host,
                user, password, database, port, NULL, CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS) == NULL) 
{
    return -1;
}
```

and delete `MYSQL *sock` parameter, and changed `sock` to `my_sql`, such as `mysql_query(sock, sql)` to `mysql_query(my_sql, sql)`. It seems workable.